# opencv4.5.5 using VideoReader can not webrtc

Tags: opencv, webrtc, video-streaming, cuvid

the stream:  webrtc://10.10.2.3/exam/2021091400479_topStream

using  RTC player  OK
[image]

but using opencv  "VideoReader"

[ERROR:0@3.701] global opencv455/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (166) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) opencv455/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'icvExtractPattern'

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.5.5) opencv455/opencv_contrib/modules/cudacodec/src/cuvid_video_source.cpp:66: error: (-217:Gpu API call) CUDA_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [Code = 301] in function 'CuvidVideoSource'

Aborted (core dumped)

[image]

## using RTMP  is OK

but RTC or WEBRTC is failed
[image]